Place images from PIL array into frame INSIDE GUI
I am brand new to Python and am working on an image filing app. I created an array extracting files from a local folder on my desktop as a test. With the code I have below I am using PIL, and can open up all the images (currently 8) separate from the GUI. How do I take an array of images and place them INTO the GUI and have them show side by side. Any feedback is greatly appreciated thank you. Code below:
import numpy as np
import customtkinter
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import glob
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

MainWindow = customtkinter.CTk()

SamplePhotos = glob.glob("C:/Users/*****/Desktop/MTGPythonPHotos/*")
images = []

for image in SamplePhotos:
    im=Image.open(image)
    im.show()
    images.append(im)
    print(image)

print(len(images))

ImageArrayText = customtkinter.CTkLabel(MainWindow, text = len(images), font = ("Arial", 30))
ImageArrayText.pack()

#DisplayedImages = Label(MainWindow, image = images)
#DisplayedImages.pack()

MainWindow.mainloop()


You can do this in PIL by converting the images to arrays, then stacking the arrays and converting them back to PIL Image objects.  However, this is difficult and essentially amounts to loading one image into the GUI, as Base64 encoded PNG.  A simpler and better solution is to iterate through a list of images and pack each as a TKinter label - those would be the last four lines of this example:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from base64 import b64encode
from io import BytesIO

import numpy as np 
from PIL import Image



root = tk.Tk()
root.title("I Am a Title")
root.geometry("1200x800")
# Load image data from disk
im = Image.open(r"path_to_sample_file.jpeg")
im = im.convert("RGB")
# Create numpy array from data, for each image 
arr = np.array(im)
# Here I'm stacking two images, but combine numpy array for multiple images here
arr = np.vstack((arr, arr))
# Convert combined numpy array back to PIL Image
merged_image = Image.fromarray(arr)

buffered = BytesIO()
merged_image.save(buffered, format="PNG")
im_as_base64 = b64encode(buffered.getvalue())

image = tk.PhotoImage(data=im_as_base64)
label = ttk.Label(image=image)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()


Not sure if you get notified if I leave a separate answer (new to Stackoverflow as well), but just wanted to say thanks. Your response was definitely helpful.


I am using PIL, and can open up all the images (currently 8) separate
from the GUI. How do I take an array of images and place them INTO the
GUI and have them show side by side

The problem can be fixed.
On line 11, change this:
SamplePhotos = glob.glob("C:/Users/*****/Desktop/MTGPythonPHotos/*")

to:
SamplePhotos = glob.glob(r"C:/Users/*****/Desktop/MTGPythonPHotos/*.png")# use 'r' case sensitive  


Thank you for that I did some research on what the "r" means, didn't even realize that was there.

https://pynative.com/python-glob/

@Alecz
Thank you for the response. Super helpful. After messing with things for a while this is what I ended up with:
    import numpy as np
    import customtkinter
    from customtkinter import *
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import *
    import glob
    import cv2
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    from base64 import b64encode
    from io import BytesIO

    CardSizeHeight=200
    CardSizeWidth=175

    MainWindow = customtkinter.CTk()

    images = []

    for image in glob.glob(r"C:/Users/*****/Desktop/MTGPythonPHotos/*.png"):
    im=CTkImage(light_image=Image.open(image), size= 
    (CardSizeWidth,CardSizeHeight))
    #images.append(im)
    #print(image)
    ImageWindow = CTkFrame(MainWindow)
    ImageWindow.pack(expand = "y")
    label = CTkLabel(ImageWindow, image=im, text="")
    label.pack(pady=5)



    print(len(images))

    #ImageArrayText = customtkinter.CTkLabel(MainWindow, text = 
    len(images), font = ("Arial", 30))
    #ImageArrayText.pack()

    MainWindow.mainloop()

Seems to work for what I need right now.
